# When reading from a binary stream, what does it mean to cast the address of a double variable to a char*?

Tags: c++

I have the following code from an online C++ course:

```
class tempStat
{
    public:
    // Data members.
    double minimum, maximum;

    // Constructor.
    tempStat(double min = 0.0, double max = 0.0)
        : minimum(min), maximum(max)
    {}

    // Helper method, to write a tempStat object to a file in binary format.
    void write(std::ostream & os)
    {
        os.write((char*)&minimum, sizeof(double));
        os.write((char*)&maximum, sizeof(double));
    }

    // Helper method, to read a tempStat object from a file in binary format.
    void read(std::istream & is)
    {
        is.read((char*)&minimum, sizeof(double));
        is.read((char*)&maximum, sizeof(double));
    }
}
```

This class is used like so:

```
tempStat ts;
ts.read(ifile);
```

**My question is**, how can we cast a memory address (`&minimum`) as a pointer to a `char`?

Secondly, if `minimum` had been an `int`, presumably we'd have written the same code (at least, as far as `(char*)&minimum`), so how does it work that `&someIntVariable` can *also* be cast as a `char*`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information in the stream is presented in the form of a sequence of bytes (`char`s).

You want to read that information into the variables `minimum` and `maximum`, which are `double`s.

You assume that the bytes you're reading constitute a valid byte representation of a `double` on your system.

You "alias" the `double`s as a sequence of bytes (this is permitted as a special rule in the standard; generally you can't just pretend something is something else), then give the resulting `char*` to the stream's "read" function.

The stream's "read" function thinks it's being asked to put the data into an array of `char`, because that's what a `char*` looks like, and because that's what the function is designed to do.

Thus, the sequence of bytes is copied by the "read" function, into your `double`s.

---

It's the same with the `write` function. We're pretending to the stream that we're giving it a sequence of bytes (a `char` array) to write, and we're allowed to do that because that's fundamentally what a `double` *is*, underneath it all.

---

> Secondly, if minimum had been an int, presumably we'd have written the same code (at least, as far as (char*)&minimum), so how does it work that &someIntVariable can also be cast as a char*?

Because an `int` is represented by a sequence of bytes, too.

Every object is.